# How do I share a track with another SoundCloud member from the mobile version of the web app?

Tags: android, soundcloud

I am a SoundCloud member and when I try to access the mobile version of the web app (or the Android app) there seems to be no way to share a sound with another SoundCloud member.

Is this the case or am I missing something?

I tried to get help on the SoundCloud website but the help area just said there were 22 FAQ's matching my question and left me there. Needless to say they didn't actually resemble my question at all ... ( but SoundCloud itself looks great if I could just get sharing from my tablet).

EDIT: I just realize I haven't mentioned that I know how to do this while uploading/creating a new recording but not how to do it with recordings that are already in existence.

Comment: Have you tried emailing Soundcloud support? Also, try this question on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. Actually that's why I posted here there was nowhere apparent to email them it seemed ... but I did find a "contact a human" button on my second search just now ... so I emailed them now ... I put a question on the android SE but there's not much soundcloud activity there I think so not holding my breath.

Comment: no worries - thanks for the edits :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mathis](https://soundcloudcommunity.com/share-embed-230064/can-t-share-private-tracks-on-app-7354859) ("8 months ago"):

> Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to share private tracks on our mobile app. However, you can a) share the secret link for the track via email from a computer web browser, or b) change the privacy settings via a computer web browser, or via the SoundCloud Pulse app.